# How to use self referencing structures in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am learning self-referenced structures in C. What is the error in the following code? How do I make it work ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
  char grade;
  struct student *ptr_dat;  //we have a pointer of datatype struct student.
};

int main()
{
  struct student data;
  struct student data1;
  data.grade = 'C';
  data1.grade = 'B';

  data.ptr_dat = &data1;  //the address of another structure is assigned. 

  /*
   print the element grade in both structures directly.
  */
  printf("%c\n",data.grade);
  printf("%c\n",data1.grade);
  /*
   how to print the element grade in data1 using pointer
  */
  printf("%c\n",data.(*ptr_dat)); //This is error.

  return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll let you in on a little secret... When the compiler says "error", all the rest of the message will actually tell you what the error is!!!  Please don't come here and treat humans as if they are compilers.  If you don't _understand_ the error message, then at the very least indicate to us that you have read it.

Comment: The term "self-referenced" is missleading. C does not have references and a `struct` cannot reference itself. You just have a pointer in your `struct` which can **point** to an object of the same type. That is not different from a pointer to any other type.

Comment: No idea.  If only compilers issued error messages that hinted at the problem and on which line it was found....

Comment: @paddy, 
Thank you for the comment.  I am a real beginner and had no clue that it was a simple syntax error. Next time I ask a question like this, I will remember to add any error message as well.

Answer (score 6):

Simple syntax error : you can access `data1`'s grade with `data.ptr_dat->grade`.

Comment: Which, for clarity, is equivalent to `(*data.ptr_dat).grade`.  In practice, everybody would use the `->` operator.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't get your answer. Can you please explain how it is equivalent?

Comment: @RAJKUMARMISHRA, it follows directly from the definitions of the operators involved, including their relative precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Quentin's answer a bit...

In order to access the member of a struct instance, you must use an expression like

*`struct-expression`*`.`*`member-name`*

where *`struct-expression`* is an expression of `struct` type (such as the struct names `data` or `data1`).  The type of the expression is the type of the member; thus, the type of the expression `data.grade` is `char`, and the type of `data.ptr_dat` is `struct student *` (pointer to `struct student`).

So, if you want to dereference `data.ptr_dat`, you must write `*data.ptr_dat`; IOW, you are dereferencing the *expression* `data.ptr_dat`.  The expression is parsed as `*(data.ptr_dat)`, since the `.` member selection operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator.

If you want to access a member of the *pointed-to* `struct` instance, you would dereference `data.ptr_dat` and use the `.` operator:

```
printf( "%c\n", (*data.ptr_dat).grade );
```

Remember that `.` has higher precendence than unary `*`, so we have to use parentheses to make sure that we are dereferencing `data.ptr_dat`, not `data.ptr_dat.grade`.

That's a little eye-stabby, so C introduced an alternate member selection operator, `->`.  Where `.` expects its left-hand operand to have a `struct` type, the `->` operator expects its left operand to have a *pointer* to `struct` type, so you can write the expression above as

```
printf( "%c\n", data.ptr_dat->grade );
```

The `->` operator implicitly dereferences `data.ptr_dat` before accessing `grade`.

This will make life easier if you chain a bunch of `struct`s together through pointers.  Given the following code:

```
struct student data1, data2, data3, *datap;
data2.ptr_dat = &data3;
data1.ptr_dat = &data2;
datap = &data1;
```

then all of the following expressions evaluate to the same thing:

```
data3.grade 

data2.ptr_dat->grade
(*data2.ptr_dat).grade

data1.ptr_dat->ptr_dat->grade
(*data1.ptr_dat).ptr_dat->grade
(*(*data1.ptr_dat).ptr_dat).grade 

datap->ptr_dat->ptr_dat->grade 
(*datap).ptr_dat->ptr_dat->grade
(*(*datap).ptr_dat).ptr_dat->grade
(*(*(*datap).ptr_dat).ptr_dat).grade
```